# Looking for free program, similar to 3D Analyst, to visualize tree stands in 3D

Tags: open-source-gis, 3d, 3d-analyst

I want to make a 3D stand visualization of trees in a specific area. I need something similar in functionality to ArcGIS 3D Analyst, but I don't have a license for that plugin anymore.

The only alternative I have found is the [Stand Visualization System from the USDA Forest](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/svs.html) Service, which works quite well, but has no GIS functionality.

I want to visualize the height and clustering of geographically referenced trees. There have to be different models for the tree species (spruce, beech, ... ).

EDIT:
For all people searching for more tools
-> [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/what-are-some-3d-visualisation-tools-that-successfully-work-with-gis-data/) is another posting on gis.stack

Comment: GRASS GIS http://grass.osgeo.org/download/

Comment: wonderful comment. Of course i know Grass gis and i use it intensively. Can you name me a function how to produce a graphic like this -> http://www.innovativegis.com/basis/present/GIS98_vis/GIS98_vis_files/image028.gif

Comment: @Curlew I don't have an answer for you, but I do have a question: do you have a census of this forest, or are you modeling sampling plots?

Comment: I found this, which seems to have a geographic component: http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/envision.html

Comment: The workflow should be the same, but i have a point layer with columns "species", "height" and so on (sampling plots). I want to display the stand in a 3-dimensional way with correct clustering of the trees (distance between them) and different tree models per species. Thanks for this first link, will see what i can do with it.

Comment: Something similar to the functions the Arcgis 3DAnalyst extensions provides. I want to display different 3-dimensional models (trees) on several point locations (point layer). Similar to this graphic (http://tinyurl.com/ck8dvjm), but instead with different tree species and not houses. See my post below

Comment: @Curlew, That image is classic output from the Forest Vegetation Simulator (FVS) via the Stand Visualization System (SVS). Given the nature of the model, it will take some playing around to get the specific results you want. You may be able to create this type of output from the LANDIS-II model: http://www.landis-ii.org/

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thanks for posting the link! I'll take a look at it, too. Damn, there are so many options out there, but all seem to be complete independent projects with different structures and syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in the end i will stay with the USGS Envison system. Their [stand visualization system](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/svs.html) in fact has a geographical component, but prior to the visualization you have to format your data locations corresponding to your plot size.

- First create a tbl file with the following parameter (From the Tbl2svs help)

> ```
>     The following example shows a stand table that lists individual
>       trees and down logs using the optional parameters:
>
>       ;sp dbh ht  crn crown stat plt crn exp   X     Y   mark fell  end
>       ;           rat rad        cls cls                 stat angle dia
>       DF  28  152 .41 19.6   1    0  0   1.0  26.4  57.9  0    0    0.0
>       RA  14   72 .58  9.6   1    0  0   1.0  98.1 121.5  0    0    0.0
>       DF  42   53 .00  0.0   0    0  0   1.0 174.8  21.4  0   72   28.0
>       DF  78  197 .39 26.4   1    0  0   1.0 142.4 171.9  0    0    0.0
>       RC  62  162 .71 17.5   1    0  0   1.0  48.2 157.1  0    0    0.0
> ```

- Then run the tbl2svs converter tool with your generated table as input.
- Then display your trees with the WinSVS tool
  [image]
- This works for simple plots. If you want to display whole landscapes take a look at the [Envision](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/envision.html) programm mentioned above, where you can load in your SVS-files and also display objects from SHP files with a height attribute.
  [image]

I'll write a r-script to accomplish this task for me step by step.

This works for me right now, but i'm really eager to see some similar applications using the VTP software or the mentioned grass-gis addon.
Feel free to use this thread to display similar workflows.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [Virtual Terrain Project](http://vterrain.org/).

> The goal of VTP is to foster the creation of tools for easily
>   constructing any part of the real world in interactive, 3D digital
>   form.
>
> This goal will require a synergetic convergence of the fields of CAD,
>   GIS, visual simulation, surveying and remote sensing. VTP gathers
>   information and tracks progress in areas such as procedural scene
>   construction, feature extraction, and rendering algorithms. VTP writes
>   and supports a set of software tools, including an interactive runtime
>   environment (VTP Enviro). The tools and their source code are freely
>   shared to help accelerate the adoption and development of the
>   necessary technologies.

[image]

Comment: VTP indeed is a promising project. I surfed a little bit through the web and noticed that there is already a basic qgis plugin to link VTP with QGIS raster files and so on (http://tinyurl.com/cvw59w4). However iam still struggling through the compiling of VTP on Linux

Answer (score 2):

[Bioshere 3D](http://www.biosphere3d.org/) sounds like it may have the functionality you need.  There is a tutorial titled [Biosphere3D Tutorial on the Visualization of Forest Stands in British Columbia](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/biosphere3d/index.php?title=Forest_Tutorial#Biosphere3D_Tutorial_on_the_Visualization_of_Forest_Stands_in_British_Columbia), where they state:

> Biosphere3D is an open source digital globe that is specialized on the
>   realistic representation of vegetation. In contrast to GoogleEarth, it
>   is open source and it is possible to import your own digital terrain
>   models, orthophotos and 3d models of buildings. Through an advanced
>   level-of-detail management Biosphere3D is able to show 3 Mio. trees
>   and more in one scene. Therefore, it is very well suited for visual
>   landscape assessment or for the visualization of future landscapes.
>   Vegetation is distributed on basis of point shapefiles which can
>   easily be generated from Vegetation Resource Inventory VRI. In
>   conclusion, it is a very potential approach to visualization of forest
>   in British Columbia and the following tutorial shows how to do that.

As it appears you can input point shapefiles, there seems to be a lot of potential here.

[image]

Comment: another great suggestion. I'll download it and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

There's a cloud-based solution at [GaiaStudio](http://gaias2dio.com) -- still in prototype, but worth a look.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a GRASS-GIS Add-on [v.trees3d](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6#v.trees3d) for version 6 that can be used to create 3D visualisations of forests.

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

If you format your data in an x,y,z flatfile format you can treat it like lidar data and use [FUSION](http://www.fs.fed.us/eng/rsac/fusion) for 3D visualization with image backdrops.